# Outlook - AddIn | Roaming Setting Sync and Save Error | Yomen Office - React and Javascript

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

**Requirement:**
**Admin** needs to add his/her **API Keys** and keys will be stored in **Roaming Settings**, adding this **API Keys** is a one time process.
When **Admin** clicks on **Customer** email, we will call our business API and **Customer** information will be shown on the **Taskpane**

**API Keys:**
Every admin will have his/her own API Keys for our business API.

**Issue we are facing:**
We tried to store the **API keys** using the **Roaming Settings**, When we added the **API Keys** in Outlook Desktop and Web version, It's working fine. But if we tried to add the **API keys** via Outlook ios or android app, **API Keys** are not getting saved.

We are using the below code to save the keys.

```
const saveSetting = async (data, callback) => {
  Office.context.roamingSettings.set("keys", data);
  await Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
      callback(false);
    } else {
      callback(true);
    }
  });
};
```

**Note:**
In Outlook ios and andorid case, We getting the success message but when we tried to fetch the keys which we stored, it's empty.